# is there IAP (In App Purchases) for react-native-macos

Tags: typescript, react-native, in-app-subscription, mac-app-store, react-native-macos

Hi there I hope you are fine.

I'm developing Mac App using react-native-macos. I need to implement the subscription using this npm package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap

I'm stuck there. That's why I'm asking the question.

If any body have luck about that?

#react-native #react-native-macos #iap #in-App-purchases #macApp

i've tried this npm package but no luck.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap

I need to implement the In App Purchases on Mac App which is developed in react-native-macos.

Any body have any solution?

It'll be really so much appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: What problem were you having? using IAP

Comment: The products are not fetching in the macos-app.

Comment: const getItems = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('itemSubs ', itemSubs);

      const Products = await RNIap.getSubscriptions({skus: itemSubs});
      // const Products = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(itemSubs);
      // let Products = await RNIap.getProducts({skus: [itemSubs]});
      console.log('inApp  ' + Products);
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.warn('IAP error ==> ', err.code, err.message, err);
      toastShow('error', 'IAP Errror');
    }
  };

@Shivo'ham0

Comment: And I'm facing this issue.

IAP error ==>  undefined Unsupported Platform [Error: Unsupported Platform]